# ¿Cómo hacer que un input obtenga un valor " " al dar clic en un botón usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que limpiar los campos, o preferiblemente enviarles un espacio en blanco en comillas (`""`), al momento de presionar el botón *Delete*. Esto con el fin de dar una apariencia de eliminar y al volver al dar clic en el `checkbox` los campos aparezcan "limpios".

Este es mi código:

```js
function action(){
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('visita1').style.display = 'none';
}

function mas1() {
 if (document.getElementById('yesCheck1').checked) {
   document.getElementById('visita1').style.display = 'block';
  }
 else document.getElementById('visita1').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:mas1();" name="yesno" 
     id="yesCheck1" > Visita 1</td>
<div id="visita1" style="display:block">
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Pedro">
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="34">
<button onclick="action()">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Agradecería que me ayudaran con JavaScript, por que desconozco por completo JQuery.

Comment: usa `value` en vez de `innerHTML`

Comment: ... Jajaja fue mas fácil de lo que pensaba. Gracias :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `value` en vez de `innerHtml` ya que esto modifica el elemento en si:

```js
   function action(){
     
     document.getElementById("name").value = "";
     document.getElementById("age").value = "";
     document.getElementById('visita1').style.display = 'none';
    
     }
     
     function mas1() {
         if (document.getElementById('yesCheck1').checked) {
             document.getElementById('visita1').style.display = 'block';
         }
         else document.getElementById('visita1').style.display = 'none';
         }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:mas1();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck1" > Visita 1
     <div id="visita1" style="display:block">
     <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Pedro">
     <input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="34">
     <button onclick="action()">Delete</button>
     </div>
```

Comment: Excelente. Gracias!

Comment: Me alegra que te haya ayudado. Si te sirvio, recuerda marcarla como aceptada.